# Expect: Easy way to check response for variable inside expect response

Tags: variables, response, expect

I am looking to see if there is an easy way to determine whether there is a loaded variable in an expect response similar to the one below. (Note $sb is switched out)

```
expect {
    "some text\rsome text = $sb\rsome text = $sb\r# " {
        id $sb
        version
        id $sb
        thermometer $eFile
        finish $eFile
    }
    "some text\rsome text = $sb\r# "    {
        id $sb
        update
        enum 2 $sb $eFile
    }
}
```

As you might imagine, this is just part of the script, all the calls within the if's are proc's.  I'd like to be able to have something similar to this than have to deal with creating enough responses manually to deal with the variants of the responses.  The result would be similar to this, only longer and more of a pain to keep track of:

```
expect {
    "some text\rsome text = 2\rsome text = 2\r# " {
        if { $sb == 2 } {
            id $sb
            version
            id $sb
            thermometer $eFile
            finish $eFile
        } else {
            assign $sb $eFile
            enum 1 $sb $eFile
        }

    }
    "some text\rsome text = 3\r# "  {
        if { $sb == 3 } {
            id $sb
            update
            enum 2 $sb $eFile
        } else {
            assign $sb $eFile
            enum 1 $sb $eFile
        }
    }
}
```

The 'some text' response is the same, so filtering through trims is interesting to say the least. I've got the majority of that built, but I'd like to avoid it if I can. Also, for the 2/3 showing, they can switch, so the response with 2 variables can have 3 and the one with 1 variable can have 2 as well, so it's obvious this could get large fast.